# VS Code, used with clang++, shows errors in a C++ file that builds fine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang++

This is solved. I deleted `c_cpp_properties.json` and allowed Vs Code to regenerate it by running the command `c/c++ configuration (JSON)`

---

I'm trying to set up Vscode for use with C++ files, following the directions here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

And the file *builds and runs okay.*

The problem is that I get errors (red squiggles) at two places in the file. One of them says "expected ;" (that's on the line with the declared `vector<string>` ) and the other one says something like "range based loop is C++11 extension"

The sample file they give is

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    vector<string> msg{"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};


    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The tasks.json I used is

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json says:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: What's in your `c_cpp_properties.json` file?

Comment: Does the `.vscode\c_cpp_properties.json` have `"cppStandard": "c++17",`?

Comment: I added a copy of `c_cpp_properties.json`

Comment: (I'm not a Mac user, BTW).  What happens if you edit the `c_cpp_properties.json` to use `"defines": ["_DEBUG","UNICODE", "_UNICODE"]`?  Say, under the `includePath` section.  Also, try: `"intelliSenseMode": "${default}"` and `"browse": { "path": ["${workspaceFolder}"], "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,`.

Comment: @MarkMoretto: no improvement with your suggested changes

Comment: Question updated: this is solved. I uninstalled and reinstalled the C++ extension. I uninstalled another extension that I had activated without really be sure it was needed (the "clang adapter"). I then deleted `c_cpp_properties.json`. and had the C++ extension regenerate it. Presto it works

Comment: @composerMike Okay. Thanks for trying my suggestion and glad to see you got it fixed!

Comment: If this is solved, make it an answer and mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I'm not sure which exact step solved it, but I can provide some useful information here for people who encounter this in the future.

First of all, be careful which C++ extensions you have enabled. Stick with the Microsoft C/C++ extension (the main one) at first.

Second, make sure the extension is enabled. There seems to be a way to install extensions without enabling them.

Third, VS Code will regenerate certain `json` files after you blow them away. For example, I deleted the `c_cpp_properties.json` file, then from the command palette ran "C/C++ Edit Configurations (JSON)" and the file was back, probably fixing whatever problem I had.